# VLC Command line for extracting audio from a video?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, mp3, video-conversion

I am using VLC for extracting/converting audio from a `.mp4` video to a `.mp3`.

The screenshot below shows the menu option I am choosing
[image]
and then 
[image]

My question is, how do I do this using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
cvlc INFILE --no-sout-video --sout-audio --sout="#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=320,channels=2,samplerate=48000}:std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=OUTFILE.mp3}"
```

with

- acodec - audio codec
- ab - audio bitrate

The only problem when I try it is that cvlc does not exit after finishing the transcode. I don't know why. I have to use CTRL+C when the size of the output file does not change anymore.

References:

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Extract_audio/

Comment: Will this work on MacOS?

Comment: Good question. I admit I tested it only on Linux, but the syntax should be the same. Why don't you just give it a try?

Have a look at the macOS section here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Command-line_interface/

Comment: I tried it and it works, MasOS does not seem to have cvlc, I tried VLC and kept the rest of the line as you provided. I got the following message 'VLC[6306:1015241] Can't find app with identifier com.spotify.client', but the mp3 is created and works fine.

Comment: To quit, add `vlc://quit` at the end of the command.

Comment: I know that this is a really old thread, but I have the same problem and addind a "vlc://quit" at the end didn't help... any hints?